# export output into text file and open in automatically in r?

Tags: r

I export my output file into a text file. Using two type of function.

```
sink()
write.table()
```

My `list` content is exported using `sink()` and `data.frame` content is exported using `write.table()`.

Is it possible to open the text file automatically after created?

please give example .

I create text file into two way..

`write.table(x, file ="F:\\frequent itemset.txt",row.names=FALSE,sep="=")`

here x is data frame..And

```
sink("F:\\Large itemset.txt") 
print(mylist) 
sink() 
print(mylist)
```

mylist is list data structure

Below code is used to open a `data.frame` in .csv file...

Is there any simpler way other than this?

```
myView <- function(dframe) {
# RStudio does not have a good viewer for large data frames.  This
# function writes a dataframe to a temporary .csv and then opens it,
# presumably in excel (if that is the file association).
csvName <- paste0(tempdir(), "\\myView-", substitute(dframe),
     format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%S"), ".csv")
write.csv(dframe, file = csvName)
shell.exec(csvName)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how package `RMark` opens a notepad on windows every time you call `print` on `mark` object. On non-Windows OS, you have to use another editor, obviously.

```
system(paste(shQuote("notepad"), "test.txt", sep = " "))
```

*EDIT*

Here is a self contained example of how to make up mock data, save it to a table and open it using a notepad.exe.

```
mydf <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = runif(10))
filename <- "test.csv"
write.table(mydf, file = filename, sep = ",", row.names = FALSE)

system(paste(shQuote("notepad"), filename, sep = " "), wait = FALSE, invisible = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: please give example .
i create textfile into two way..
 write.table(x, file ="F:\\frequent itemset.txt",row.names=FALSE,sep="=")

here x is data frame..

Comment: And 

 sink("F:\\Large itemset.txt")
      print(mylist)
      sink()
      print(mylist)

Comment: mylist is list data structure

Comment: @user3398594 `"test.txt"` can be replace with your `csvName`.

Comment: i load . 
library("RMark")
write.table(new, file ="F:\\frequent itemset.txt",row.names=FALSE,sep="=")
system(paste(shQuote("notepad"), "F:\\Large itemset.txt", sep = " "))
but not working

Answer (score 0):

If your question in 'only' about *viewing* data frames, you may have a look at the `gvisTable` function in package `googleVis`.

"The gvisTable function reads a data.frame and creates text output referring to the Google Visualisation API, which can be included into a web page, or as a stand-alone page. The actual chart is rendered by the web browser."

There are loads of nice tutorials on `googleVis`, e.g. the [**vignette**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis.pdf). Here is just a very simple example.

```
library(googleVis)
gt <- gvisTable(iris)
plot(gt)

gt <- gvisTable(iris, options = list(page = 'enable', height = 300))
plot(gt)
```

Comment: my question is showing ouput.not data frame...how it work?..i cant show my output using this

Comment: tbl2 <- gvisTable(Population, options=list(page='enable', height=300))

plot(tbl2)

if i enter this codeeach time viewer in rstudio change and always show as empty

Comment: @user3398594, I think you need to clarify your needs. In your question you write: "code is used to open a data.frame"; "RStudio does not have a good viewer for large data frames"; "function writes a dataframe to a temporary .csv". Then in comment:  "my question is showing ouput.not data frame.".

Comment: i meant, there is two type of data structure that why i said" not data frame".
i didn't get the gvisTable working